# How to Display hidden <tr> closest to selected radiobutton's <tr>

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-table, tablerow

I have 3 tables on a page. Each of them contain two table rows.

The first `<tr>` holds a RadioButton. The second `<tr>` is set to display: none. I need to second `<tr>` to display when the RadioButton in that particular table was selected.

My HTML:

```
<table class="tableClass" style="width: 98%">   
    <tr>
       <td>
           <input type="radio" id="rbResource" onclick="radio_Click()" class="radioButton"       runat="server" />
       </td>  
    </tr>
    <tr class="displaySelection" style="display: none">
       <td>
           <span>Test</span>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure how to form my jQuery int the `radio_Click()` function to get what I'm looking for. Everything I've tried so far, displays all three `<tr>` of each table regardless of which Radiobutton was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need only 1 row to be visible each time, depending on the radiobutton pressed. To begin with, you should use **name="rbResource"** (rather than id) to group the radiobuttons together. Then you can use something like this:

```
$(".radioButton").click( function(evt) {
    $(".radioButton").each( function( index, obj ) {
        var checked = $(obj).attr('checked')==true;
        var row = $(obj).closest('tr').next();
        if ( checked ) row.show();
        else row.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work entirely. Debugging it shows that   var checked = $(obj).attr('checked') == 'checked'; returns as false every time.

Comment: I changed the == 'checked' part to == true and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:radio').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').next().show();
});
```

OR,

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').show();
});
```

Comment: @Melanie remove the `onclick()` function

Comment: This works but the problem is that if I select one radiobutton, then another, then both rows still display. Will try and adapt xpapad's code to accommodate this.